# list-style-type:none; Not working second time used in code

Tags: html, css

This is my first time working with css/html on a project.
I want to make a list in my footer and the list style type command doesn't work, while in my nav it works just fine. How can I fix this problem? It works only in the first list I use after that I can't get it to work.

```css
.footer-row{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top:2%;
}

.footer-column{
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-row">
  <div class="footer-column">
    <ul class:"footer-ul">
      <li>opening</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-column">
    <ul class:"footer-ul">
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul >
  </div>
  <div class="footer-column">
   <ul class:"footer-ul">
     <li>something</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to put it on the `ul` not the div wrapping it

Comment: can i do that like `.footer-column ul li {.....}`??

Comment: Yes but it's better to be applied to the ul not the li and leave the inheritance do the rest

Comment: can i ask you if the `.footer-column` is the only place where tis will work or is the `.footer-column ul` the line of code that makes this work(what i am asking is which one of the two lines is needed to make this work)

Comment: Look at your code. You wrote `class:"footer…"` instead of `class="footer…"`. Equal signs, not colons, assign attributes.

Comment: Well that depends on if you want to target every `ul` on the page `ul { ... }` or just the ones inside `.footer-column` which would be  `.footer-column ul { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an exmaple:

```css
.footer-row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.footer-column {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
}

.footer-column ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-row">
  <div class="footer-column">
    <ul class="footer-ul">
      <li>opening</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-column">
    <ul class="footer-ul">
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-column">
    <ul class="footer-ul">
      <li>something</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.footer-row{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-top:2%;

    }

     ul{
     
   display:flex;
   border: 1px solid black;
   list-style: none;
   justify-content:space-evenly;
 }
 
 li{
 border:solid 1px black;
 padding:10px;
 margin:10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="footer-row">
          <div class="footer-column">
            <ul class:"footer-ul">
              <li>opening</li>
              <li>Contact</li>
              <li>something</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          
        </div>
```

Comment: I don't get it, the question is about list-style-type. You made unnecessary changes and just dumped code without explaining it.

Comment: the op code really doesn't make any sense. Why would you use 3 different ul's for this?